# "Syntax error near unexpected token '$'\r''" in shell script

Tags: bash

I am writing a script am I am getting an error on lines 2-3. The error is printed like this:

```
./ex6.sh: line2: $'\r': command not found
./ex6.sh: line3: syntax error near unexpected token '$'\r''
./ex6.sh: line3: 'fund ()
```

The file is called `ex6.sh`. Could someone provide some guidance as to why this error is happening?

```
#!/bin/sh

func () 
{
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
echo "Default";
for i in `find` ; 
do
    if [ -d $i ]; then
        echo $i "is a directory";
    fi
    if [ -f $i ]; then
        if [ "$i" != "./script.sh" ]; then
            echo $i "is a file";        
        fi
    fi
done
fi

if [ "$1" == "--long" ]; then
echo "--long";
for i in `find` ; 
do
    if [ -d $i ]; then
        echo $i "is a directory";
    fi
    if [ -f $i ]; then
        echo $i "is a file";        
    fi
done
fi

if [ "$1" == "--rm" ]; then
echo "--rm";
for i in `find` ; 
do
    if [ -d $i ]; then
        echo $i "is a directory";
    fi
    if [ -f $i ]; then
        echo $i "is a file";        
    fi
done
fi
}

getArgs () {
if [ "$1" == "--long" ]; then
    echo "got the first param $1";
else
    if [ "$1" == "--rm" ]; then
        echo "got the second param $1";
    else
        if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
            echo "got default param";
        else
            echo "script.sh: unknown option $1";
            exit;
        fi  
    fi
fi

}

getArgs $1;
#ARGS=$1;

func $1;
```

Comment: And what's your question? Also, please take at least the 20 seconds it takes to learn how to insert formatted code into your post on this site.

Comment: Your script probably can't handle file names that contain spaces. Any white space is considered a divider in collections (e.g. `find` return values), not just newlines.

Comment: I couldnt get multiple lines into the format box for code. Cygwin says there is an error on line 2.

Comment: the error is ./ex6.sh: line2: syntax error near unexpected tkey '$'{\r''
./ex6.sh: line 2: 'e {} {

Comment: That's what I meant by 20 seconds: That's my estimation how long it'll take you to press the question mark link/button, then on *Code*, and read that you need to indent multiple lines for pre formatted text.

Comment: Cygwin is a set of libraries and executables. It doesn't say anything.

Comment: **Edit your old question**, please don't post a new one. I already did this for you, but please remember it for the future.

Answer (score 10):

Use `dos2unix` or a proper text editor to convert all your line breaks from Windows `\r\n` to `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

Check the end line character in the file. Probably you have Windows style (<kbd>CR</kbd> + <kbd>LF</kbd>) and you should have Unix/Linux style (only <kbd>LF</kbd>).